# Currency convert based on geolocation

Tags: geolocation, currency

I am working on wordpress elementor. I tried some plugins for currency conversion but didn't worked out. As my pricing  is mentioned in the text box, i didn't rectify the problem that how can i convert the currency based on geolocation. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: You may consider using API for this. One API will get you the currency of the geolocation and another will convert your currency to the user's currency.

Comment: Thanks but how can i do that in wordpress. I am new to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

These work WooCommerce Currency Converter by Geolocation and https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-geoplugin/

https://cfgeoplugin.com/tutorial/woocommerce-currency-conversion-by-geolocation

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-geoplugin/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).